# How to include another web file in C# ASP.NET (VS 2010)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to include a common navigation page into each aspx page. The code looks something like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"      Inherits="canada_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <%         
        Response.WriteFile("../include/navigation.aspx");
    %>

</div>
</form>
```

Here is the navigation.aspx code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSites" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSites_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Global websites" Value="" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Australia" Value="" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Canada" Value="" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Ireland" Value="" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Japan" Value="" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Latin America and the Caribbean" Value="" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Middle East" Value="" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="New Zealand" Value="" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Portugal" Value="" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Singapore" Value="" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Spain" Value="" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="United Kingdom" Value="" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="United States" Value="" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

The dropdownlist is not displaying in the browser. I know one way is to use a Master page (which I plan on doing one day), but for this project, I would like to do something simple like this -- it's crude but functional.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why not leaving out the crude and obviously non-functional way and use a Master Page from the start?

Comment: I agree with Filburt: considering the question, it's obviously non-functional and therefore you should go back to common practices and use a master page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at using User Controls: [ASP.NET User Controls Overview (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3w5b53.aspx).

Quote from the MSDN page:

> User controls are substantially easier
>   to create than custom controls,
>   because you can reuse existing
>   controls. They make it particularly
>   easy to create controls with complex
>   user interface elements.

Also, take a look at this MSDN link: [How to: Include a User Control in an ASP.NET Web Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbz9etab.aspx)

You would create your User Control (.ascx) and include it as follows:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"      Inherits="canada_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="uc1" Src="~/myUserControl.ascx" %>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <uc:uc1 id="myUC" runat="server" />
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: well i feel embarassed. i've actually used usercontrols for other aspects of my web app -_-

Comment: @user808710: I hear ya.  Sometimes the solution is something you've done a thousand times but, for whatever reason, it just isn't something you considered.

Answer (score 3):

what you want is an [old-school server-side-include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3207d0e3%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

code:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <!-- #Include virtual=".\include\header.inc" -->
      Here is the main body of the .aspx file.
      <!-- #Include virtual=".\include\footer.inc" -->
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you be more specific by old-school server-side include?

Comment: added a link to msdn, and some example code (from the msdn page)

Comment: quick question: isn't the '<!-- -->' tag for commenting?

Comment: @user808710 that is corrrect. you can remove those, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an easy way to achieve this would be to use a User Control.